# Pandas Dataframes - Get the dataframe's overall top 5 values and their row and column labels, not by column or by row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame, let's say its named "df", with numerical values inside it in all columns (floats). I want to retrieve the top 5 highest absolute values from the dataframe, together with their row and column labels.

I've seen suggestions like:

```
df.abs().stack().nlargest(5)
```

but the `stack` method doesn't keep the row and column labels for all elements, it enumerates one of the axis and, for each element, then enumerates the other axis, with a blank element before. I need the value and the names of BOTH the column and the row.

I know I can do this by iterating over each column, then each row inside it, then accessing the value and appending to 3 lists, one with row names, other with column names and a third with the values, then copying the values list to have a fourth list with the absolute values, using this last list to get the positions of the 5 highest values, and using those positions to index the first 3 lists, therefore getting the row name, column name and value. There must be a better, more compact and more pythonic way though, but I seriously cannot find it anywhere, and I am usually good at gooling my issues away.

Comment: You want only the row and column labels? Not the dataframe with the top 5 values ? It would help if you could paste your dataframe and expected output.

Comment: `stack` method does keep the row and column labels, you can try `df.stack().nlargest(5).reset_index()` and see them in the `level_0` and `level_1` columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested solution contains the row and column labels in the index and are not lost.

A simple example where the appropriate names are reattached:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.random(100), 'b': np.random.random(100)})

df.abs().stack().nlargest(5).rename('value').rename_axis(['row', 'column']).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
  row  column     value
0  87       a  0.958382
1  49       a  0.953590
2  55       a  0.952150
3  31       b  0.949763
4   4       b  0.931452
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked just as I wanted it, now every entry had the row and column labels.

Comment: @Slna: Glad it worked out for you, happy to help :)